# Perl script for parsing a log file

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

Once again, I'm asking for help from this community, with the following Perl script.  It uses [`Excel::Writer::XLSX`][Excel::Writer::XLSX] to parse large (2GB) log files and write the output to an Excel spreadsheet.

While most of the script is correct, my `push` and the lines

```
$worksheet->write($row, 1, $key, $format );
$worksheet->write($row, 5, $eventdetail{"$key"}, $format );
```

Comment: I think you need to explain what it is you're trying to do, and show the real log data that you're processing. The `%eventdetail` hash you've created is a hugely complex hash nested severn levels deep, and I doubt if that is what you intended. The value `$eventdetail{$key}` (the quotes are superfluous - Excel never sees them) is trying to write *hash reference* to the spreadsheet, which doesn't make any sense but it is far from clear what you *do* intend.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree that *"most of the script is correct"*. It is a mess, and there is a *lot* more wrong than the problems you describe.

For instance you seem to expect `\w` to match a colon `:` which it doesn't, and you are using capture variables `$1`, `$2` etc. without any corresponding capture in the the regex. And `$0` isn't even a capture at all but contains the name of the currently-running Perl program file.

It won't affect the functionality of your code, but keeping the regexes as strings means you are unnecessarily compiling them over and over again at run time, which will slow things down a lot. Far better to write, e.g.

```
my $integrity_regex = qr/^Integrity checksum changed for: (.*)$/;
if ($line =~ $integrity_regex) { ... }
```

then the pattern is compiled just once at compile time.

The line

```
$line =~ /$$user_name_regex/
```

tries to dereference a string as if it was a scalar reference, which is clearly wrong.

You declare variables `$user_name`, `$account_name` and `$source_addr` *within* the loop, so they are deleted immediately after you assign to them.

There is probably a lot more wrong, but it is far easier for you to debug your own programming when you have the live data at hand, than it is for me to scrutinise your programming for mistakes.

You appear to have written the whole program from scratch without testing any if it until it is "finished". That is the wrong way to go: you should write incrementally and test each part as you add it.

I suggest you start to fix things by checking every regex against the line from the log file that it is supposed to match.

Comment: Can you direct me to a source of knowledge. I spent the last 4 days trying to figure this out, and I'm obviously breaking it more as I go by. I'm not a programmer in no means. I was suggested to use Perl for my log parsing needs, so I'v been putting a lot of time in learning it, but obviously I'm terrible at it.

Comment: @GerogeGZ: Don't give up hope. Perl is great for what you want to do. Take a look at [Perl Maven](http://perlmaven.com/) and the other stuff on www.perl-tutorial.org. If you want something solid I would suggest Curtis Poe's book _Beginning Perl_.

Comment: @boroding: are you saying that in general all my if statements found in variables should follow your suggestion if ($line =~ $integrity_regex) ?

Comment: @simbabque: Followed as suggested.

Comment: I'm saying that, if you want to store a regular expression in a variable, you should do just that with the `qr/.../` construct, rather than storing a *string* in the variable and using `/$regex/` thereafter.